# Divide quadrilateral into grid in Java

Tags: java

I have a convex quadrilateral. I know the four points, and I have its four lines in the format `mx + b` (from the top going clockwise). `Quadrilateral` is a class shown below:

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;

public final class Quadrilateral extends Polygon {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 794866732073166739L;
    public final Point p1, p2, p3, p4;
    public final Line l12, l23, l34, l41;

    public Quadrilateral(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3, Point p4) {
        super(new int[] { p1.x, p2.x, p3.x, p4.x }, new int[] { p1.y, p2.y,
                p3.y, p4.y }, 4);
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
        this.p3 = p3;
        this.p4 = p4;
        this.l12 = Quadrilateral.getLine(p1, p2);
        this.l23 = Quadrilateral.getLine(p2, p3);
        this.l34 = Quadrilateral.getLine(p3, p4);
        this.l41 = Quadrilateral.getLine(p4, p1);
    }

    public static final Line getLine(Point p1, Point p2) {
        if (p1.x > p2.x) {
            return Quadrilateral.getLine(p2, p1);
        } else {
            int x1 = p1.x;
            int x2 = p2.x;
            int y1 = p1.y;
            int y2 = p2.y;
            int xdiff = x2 - x1;
            int ydiff = y1 - y2;
            double m = (double) ydiff / (double) xdiff;
            double b = y1 - m * x1;
            return new Line(m, b);
        }
    }

    public Quadrilateral[][] grid(int x, int y) {...?...}
}
```

What I want to do is to divide an instance of `Quadrilateral` into an `x` by `y` grid of Quadrilaterals, sorted in a `Quadrilateral[][]`. How would I do this efficiently?

Comment: use vectors to define the lines or you'll run into problems if a line is vertical and `xdiff==0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found out the answer! It's quite lengthy. I've included the whole `Quadrilateral.java` file below:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public final class Quadrilateral extends Polygon {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 794866732073166739L;
    public final Point p1, p2, p3, p4;
    public final Line l12, l23, l34, l41;

    public Quadrilateral(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3, Point p4) {
        super(new int[] { p1.x, p2.x, p3.x, p4.x }, new int[] { p1.y, p2.y,
                p3.y, p4.y }, 4);
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
        this.p3 = p3;
        this.p4 = p4;
        this.l12 = Quadrilateral.getLine(p1, p2);
        this.l23 = Quadrilateral.getLine(p2, p3);
        this.l34 = Quadrilateral.getLine(p3, p4);
        this.l41 = Quadrilateral.getLine(p4, p1);
    }

    public static Quadrilateral formatted(Quadrilateral quadrilateral, int w,
            int h) {
        return new Quadrilateral(Format.format(quadrilateral.p1, w, h),
                Format.format(quadrilateral.p2, w, h), Format.format(
                        quadrilateral.p3, w, h), Format.format(
                        quadrilateral.p4, w, h));
    }

    public Quadrilateral[][] grid(int x, int y) {
        Point[][] points = new Point[x + 1][y + 1];
        for (int ix = 0; ix <= x; ix++) {
            for (int iy = 0; iy <= y; iy++) {
                points[ix][iy] = this.getPointAt(x, y, ix, iy);
            }
        }
        Quadrilateral[][] qs = new Quadrilateral[x][y];
        for (int ix = 0; ix < x; ix++) {
            for (int iy = 0; iy < y; iy++) {
                qs[ix][iy] = new Quadrilateral(points[ix][iy],
                        points[ix + 1][iy], points[ix + 1][iy + 1],
                        points[ix][iy + 1]);
            }
        }
        return qs;
    }

    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Quadrilateral>> gridList(int x, int y) {
        Point[][] points = new Point[x + 1][y + 1];
        for (int ix = 0; ix <= x; ix++) {
            for (int iy = 0; iy <= y; iy++) {
                points[ix][iy] = this.getPointAt(x, y, ix, iy);
            }
        }
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Quadrilateral>> qs = new ArrayList<>(0);
        for (int ix = 0; ix < x; ix++) {
            qs.add(new ArrayList<>(y));
            for (int iy = 0; iy < y; iy++) {
                qs.get(ix).add(
                        new Quadrilateral(points[ix][iy], points[ix + 1][iy],
                                points[ix + 1][iy + 1], points[ix][iy + 1]));
            }
        }
        return qs;
    }

    public Point getPointAt(int xdiv, int ydiv, int xiter, int yiter) {
        Point n1 = this.getTopPointAt(xdiv, xiter);
        Point n2 = this.getRightPointAt(ydiv, yiter);
        Point n3 = this.getBottomPointAt(xdiv, xiter);
        Point n4 = this.getLeftPointAt(ydiv, yiter);
        Line h = Quadrilateral.getLine(n4, n2);
        Line v = Quadrilateral.getLine(n1, n3);
        return h.intersect(v, n2.x, n1.x);
    }

    public Point getTopPointAt(int div, int iter) {
        Point start = this.p1;
        Point end = this.p2;
        int xdiff = end.x - start.x;
        int ydiff = end.y - start.y;
        int xadd = (int) ((double) xdiff / (double) div) * iter;
        int yadd = (int) ((double) ydiff / (double) div) * iter;
        int x = start.x + xadd;
        int y = start.y + yadd;
        return new Point(x, y);
    }

    public Point getBottomPointAt(int div, int iter) {
        Point start = this.p4;
        Point end = this.p3;
        int xdiff = end.x - start.x;
        int ydiff = end.y - start.y;
        int xadd = (int) ((double) xdiff / (double) div) * iter;
        int yadd = (int) ((double) ydiff / (double) div) * iter;
        int x = start.x + xadd;
        int y = start.y + yadd;
        return new Point(x, y);
    }

    public Point getLeftPointAt(int div, int iter) {
        Point start = this.p4;
        Point end = this.p1;
        int xdiff = end.x - start.x;
        int ydiff = end.y - start.y;
        int xadd = (int) ((double) xdiff / (double) div) * iter;
        int yadd = (int) ((double) ydiff / (double) div) * iter;
        int x = start.x + xadd;
        int y = start.y + yadd;
        return new Point(x, y);
    }

    public Point getRightPointAt(int div, int iter) {
        Point start = this.p3;
        Point end = this.p2;
        int xdiff = end.x - start.x;
        int ydiff = end.y - start.y;
        int xadd = (int) ((double) xdiff / (double) div) * iter;
        int yadd = (int) ((double) ydiff / (double) div) * iter;
        int x = start.x + xadd;
        int y = start.y + yadd;
        return new Point(x, y);
    }

    public static final Line getLine(Point p1, Point p2) {
        if (p1.x < p2.x) {
            return Quadrilateral.getLine(p2, p1);
        } else {
            int x1 = p1.x;
            int x2 = p2.x;
            int y1 = p1.y;
            int y2 = p2.y;
            int xdiff = x2 - x1;
            int ydiff = y2 - y1;
            double m = (double) ydiff / (double) xdiff;
            double b = y1 - m * x1;
            return new Line(m, b);
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g, BufferedImage image) {
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        Quadrilateral[][] grid = this.grid(w, h);
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                g.setColor(new Color(image.getRGB(x, y), true));
                g.fillPolygon(grid[x][y]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to interpolate to create the points in between. Do this for each component like so:

```
p1.x * (1-t) + p2.x * t
```

Where t goes from 0 to 1.

Create a grid of `x+1` by `y+1` points this way. Interpolate between two pairs of points of the outline that are neighbours (not connected via diagonals). Then interpolate again between the two points you receive as a result. Set t on each interpolation according to the values of `x` and `y` and what iteration step you are currently calculating.

From this grid of points you can build the grid of quadriliterals by iterating over the the points in steps of size 2.

Comment: What do you mean by "interpolate"?

Comment: @JamesSmith to calculate a point that is in between two points. I provided the formula for the x component of the point in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I used a method like this to create my final method. I've posted it as an answer.